# python current session doesn't exit at command line

Tags: python

I am trying to learn python and i have run simple hello function through command line but when i try to exit current session using below command it give me new line but not goes again at project folder path.

Command:

```
CTRL+C
```

Please can anyone share all commands and refer tutorial site which give me all ideas of code on python 3 latest version.

Comment: ctrl+d _should_ get you out of there.

Comment: ctrl+z is the stop command, but you might have to press it a few times, sometimes it makes you close out of the window and reopen the command line.

Comment: What OS and console are you using? (e.g. CMD/PowerShell on Windows, Gnome Terminal on Linux, Terminal on Mac OS)

Answer (score 0):

CTRL-C in the Python Interpreter is a `KeyBoard Interrupt`.  To exit the Python interpreter, run `exit()`.  The Python interpreter documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html).

Comment: I used exit but it was not working for me. it says invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

To exit a Python interpreter, you can run `exit()` or the keyboard shortcut `CTRL+D`

Comment: I used same. it say's invalid syntax

Comment: I think Ctrl+D is only for Nix, and on Windows it's Ctrl+Z, Enter.

Answer (score 0):

Run `quit()` to quit. Ctrl+C only cancels the current input.

#### Sources

[interpreter documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#invoking-the-interpreter):

> Typing an end-of-file character (**Control-D** on Unix, **Control-Z** on Windows) at the primary prompt causes the interpreter to exit with a zero exit status. If that doesn’t work, you can exit the interpreter by typing the following command: `quit()`.

[interactive mode documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/appendix.html#error-handling):

> Typing the interrupt character (usually **Control-C** or **Delete**) to the primary or secondary prompt cancels the input and returns to the primary prompt.